# Ignore styles for a particular element

Tags: html, css

Say you get a page that is already designed but they forgot to include heading tags.

Now you are asked to include h2,h3,h4 here and there.

Those tags already have styles, but you want that style to be ignored. Is there a **one line declaration that would ignore the styles instead of overwriting them one by one**?

I am looking for something like this:

```
.class-where-headings-dont-have-styles h2{
  ignore general h2 styles;
}
```

I guess I can attach a `.no-style` class to my h2 and whenever an h2 is styled add `h2:not(.no-style)` but I hope there is a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [all](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/) but it's still not implemented in [Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all).

```
.reset{
  all: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this solution works out for you:

You would use the `not()` function in css. So it would look something like this:

```
h2:not(.classwithoutheadingstyles){
/* bunch of style properties meant for other h2 elements without that class name */
}
```

If you want to add another h2 class or two into the mix, the syntax would look like this:

```
h2:not(.class1):not(.class2):not(.class3):not(#id1){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Method 1:*
Give a class name to the parent of h1,h2,h3 and apply styles
For eg:

```
<style>
.added-class h2{
    color:black;
 }

<div class="initial-class added-class">
  <h2>ABCD</h2>
</div>
```

*Method 2:*
Add class to h1,h2,h3 and apply styles using !important

```
<style>
 .added-h2{
    color:black;
 }
<style>
<h2 class="added-h2">
```